# Indicator for currently-active post filter is MIA

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

On the [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=profile), a user's questions and answers are displayed, with various sort options that are selectable with pseudo-tabs:

> [image]

It used to be that the currently active filters were indicated in some way. If I remember correctly, it was an orange underline. This is now missing, so that it is impossible to tell what filters are active.

The "hover" state is, however, still indicated:

> [image]

I suspect this is a simple CSS bug. A style definition probably got inadvertently deleted.

Please fix it! I use this section a lot, and not being able to tell which filter is active really [messes up my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: The design issue is [around the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292754/) and [Hynes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292754/selected-tab-is-not-highlighted-in-the-profile-tab-questions-answers-section?noredirect=1#comment961877_292754) is looking on the issue.

Comment: Wow, a 2 month lag time on getting simple bugs like this *investigated*. Not reassuring… Thanks for the link, @Arulkumar. I only looked at *recent* questions before posting this one, assuming it must be a very new bug.

Comment: When I initially post the question, the highlight issue is not occur for SO, but may be the [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296405/) the highlight is break in SO too.